# Alamofire Appending Data

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a simple Alamofire request and i'm parsing it with SwiftyJSON. Here is code:

```
var fetchedData: [TestDB]? = []

func fetchData() {
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)

            self.fetchedData = [TestDB]()

            for dict in json["articles"].array! {

                let data = TestDB()

                if let image = dict["urlToImage"].string {
                    data.imageUrls = image
                }

                if let titlee = dict["title"].string {
                    data.titlee = titlee
                }

                if let desc = dict["description"].string {
                    data.desc = desc
                }

                self.fetchedData?.append(data)
                // If i print fetchedData here, i can see it has right values.
                // print(fetchedData)

            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
        // If i try to print fetchedData here, it's empty.
}
```

As i said in code, i can't append and use my datas. I think that's something with **Alamofire being asynchronous**. But couldn't figure out why. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You made a small mistake.You are initialising self.fetchedData every-time in success block.That is why you are unable to append data.

Comment: @sanman yes that was a mistake. But the fixed code is still got same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use asynchronous method you have some way to proceed, for example:

- use callback
- use RAC/observation

**Callback:**

```
func fetchData(completion: (result: [TestDB]) -> ) {
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
       self.fetchedData = [TestDB]()
       // fill self.fetchedData then:
       completion(self.fetchedData) 
    }
})
```

Where you call fetchData:

```
self.fetchData(completion: { 
    // update collectionview?
    self.collectionView.reloadData() 
})
```

**RAC:**

You can find all documentation [**here**](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa).

**Plus:**

Some suggestion:

- self.fetchedData = TestDB is not necessary, probably  is sufficient self.fetchData.removeAll()
- use [ObjectMappar](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) to map any json response to object